# Remove build from review

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, review

I put in review process the version 1.0.0 of my app.
Now i would need to put directly the following version 1.0.1 (it's already available in Testflight)

I tried at first time to remove from the process review the current version, i had "developer rejected" status and seems like i cannot add a new build version for the review, so I put again the same build in review.

If I make "expire your build" I will be able to put immediatelly the new versione in review?

Thank you for the attention

Comment: ***What*** "review process"?

Comment: Hi, sorry i didn't specify i was talking about the Apple review  process in iTunes Connect

Comment: Did you change the build number or the version number?  If you have incremented the version number in your build then you need to change the version number in the App Store connect screen before you can select a build with that version.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Aniway I already solved the problem, as you said after the removal of the current version, I incremented the version number and I''ve been able to submit the new build.